# Data fusion replication sql connection issue

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

Im trying to build data fusion replication job from ms sql server (cloud sql) to big query. Both data fusion and cloud sql instances is using private IP. I have configured peering from both tenant project to VPC network and setup sql-auth proxy. Now i'm able to reach to cloud sql instance from data fusion when i create standard pipeline using source ms sql connector and sink big query connector. Pipeline run successfully without any issue.
But when i try to run replication job it gives me this error when i setup the source (same sql instance mentioned earlier)

```
The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:
```

[image: Here is my cloud sql configuration]

I'm using JDBC driver Version 12.2. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: could you confirm if you're uploading the JDBC driver as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/using-jdbc-drivers#upload-driver)?

Comment: Yes i'm following the same documentation when i upload the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

1. Referring to the Google [Data Fusion Replication docs](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/sqlserver-to-bigquery), for Microsoft SQL Server, we need to use [SQL Server CDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). Could you please verify if you have CDC enabled?
2. If after Step#1 the driver connection issue persists, another workaround at this time is to use an older JDBC version (such as version [9.4.1](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/tag/v9.4.1)). Alternatively, if you can specify the JDBC connection string, you could also try adding `trustServerCertificate=true` to the connection string. The root cause of this issue is that Microsoft enabled encryption and certificate verification in JDBC [version 10](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/tag/v10.1.0), and Cloud SQL certificates do not seem to be trusted by default.